# How to open different acitivies when click any recyclerView Items in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I got crazy ı am not able find solution. Please help me. 2 days ı am looking for solution. I clearly watn that if I click any recylerView Item starting a new activity. Each item has to own its activity.How to implement codes?. Thanks in  advance.

My adapter code:

```
class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

// create new views
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    // inflates the card_view_design view
    // that is used to hold list item
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.card_view_design, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(view)
}

// binds the list items to a view
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val ItemsViewModel = mList[position]

    // sets the image to the imageview from our itemHolder class
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(ItemsViewModel.image)

    // sets the text to the textview from our itemHolder class
    holder.textView.text = ItemsViewModel.text

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        
    }
}

// return the number of the items in the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mList.size
}

// Holds the views for adding it to image and text
class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview)
    val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
}
```

}

My recyclerview.kt :

```
class recyclerView : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityRecyclerViewBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityRecyclerViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    // getting the recyclerview by its id
    val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)

    // this creates a vertical layout Manager
    binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    // ArrayList of class ItemsViewModel
    val data = ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>()

    data.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.jumping_jack, "Jumping Jack"))
    data.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.jumping_aquats, "Jumping Squat"))


    // This will pass the ArrayList to our Adapter
    val adapter = CustomAdapter(data)

    // Setting the Adapter with the recyclerview
    recyclerview.adapter = adapter
    }

        }
```

Comment: any Solution? Not able assign any İd to items .What is method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a list object to adapter like param, you can get position of item, and use this position to start activity you want.

something like this:
add listener in your adapter

```
    class CustomAdapter(
        private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>,
        val clickListener: RecycleViewOnClickListener
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        ...
    }
```

in your bindViewHolder:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: 
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder,position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClick(position)
        }
    }
```

and add simple interface:

```
    interface RecycleViewOnClickListener {
        fun onItemCLick(position: Int)
    }
```

in your activity, get model from list with your position:

```
    class recyclerView : AppCompatActivity(), RecycleViewOnClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(pos: Int) {
             val model = yourList[pos]
             //start new activity
        }
    }
```

then when you init adapter:

```
// This will pass the ArrayList to our Adapter
    val adapter = CustomAdapter(data, this)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your kindly help. But ı cant adapt your suggest to my code. Can you make corrections on my code ? Ps: Iv edited my post with code

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try it again @cmsvs

Comment: if my answer suitable, please vote me up

Comment: val model = yourList[pos].... here I v stucked. In this code can you explain clearly? How I will code here?

Comment: Ok. Thanks little modification on your code ı did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using high order function it will be easy

In you adapter class (pass list and high order function as callback)

```
class YourAdapter(private val itemList: List<Model>, private val onItemClicked: (item) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    // your code
}
```

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {  
     onItemClicked(itemList[position])
}
```

In your activity/Fragment where you are assigning adapter assign in this way.

whenever item is clicked it will land here, and you can start your activity, you will get item also from adapter on which user clicked

```
YourAdapter(list) { item ->
     //start activity
}
```

Note: Always write some code with question, it will be easy for us to answer you and guide you what is wrong in your code.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your kindly help. But ı cant adapt your suggest to my code. Can you make corrections on my code ? Ps: Iv edited my post with code

Comment: you have to add listener in you adapter class first

`
class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>, private val onItemClicked: (ItemsViewModel) -> Unit)
`
In activity where you initialize adapter, do this 

`
val adapter = CustomAdapter(data){
     //here you will get ItemsViewModel object and you can start activity
}
`

in onBindViewHolder

`
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        onItemClicked(ItemsViewModel)
}
`